# Комментарии в вопросах

Tags: предложение

Периодически встречаюсь с таким явлением, как: участники с репутацией ниже 50 не могут оставить комментарий и пишут ответ.

Иногда бывает так, что комментарий-ответ является довольно полезным советом.
Предлагаю добавить кнопку для автора вопроса - перенос ответа в секцию комментариев.

То есть, к примеру, человек просит помощи с ошибкой в коде. Участник с репутацией ниже 50 решает дать небольшой совет (к примеру, о структуре кода - добавлять комментарии, либо хоть как-то разбивать код на блоки), либо же пишет свое мнение о том, из-за чего возникла ошибка, но не может дать **точный ответ**.

Примечание: возможно такая функция уже есть, однако не находил таковой.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Такая функция есть у модераторов. Не думаю, что надо давать авторам вопросов такие права - некоторые даже ответ принять не могут... На мой взгляд, стоит очередь проверки доработать, чтобы там вместо удаления мог быть перенос в комментарии.

Comment: Дельная мысль...

Comment: "некоторые даже ответ принять не могут." — многие;)

Comment: почему участники с репутацией ниже 50 не могут оставлять комментарий, в чём смысл??

Comment: @Iangyl, не знаю, так движок устроен. Возможно, смысл в том, чтобы все подряд не задавали кучу кучу вопросов в комментариях.